# Can't call Python entry_points from command line

Tags: python, macos, macports

I just installed a [python tool for line profiling](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) that [should ship with itself](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler/blob/master/setup.py#L68) a command line entry point named kernprof

```
$pip install line_profiler
```

a quick search returns:

```
$find /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/ -name 'kernprof.py'
opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework//Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kernprof.py
```

and the module is callable from the Python's interactive console, but

```
$which kernprof
```

does not return anything.

I suppose that this behaviour could be related to the fact that I'm using `python-2.7` from Macports on OSX OS with wrong or incomplete path settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with Macports's Python the scripts are installed in `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/` that is not in the `PATH`.

The lighter solution could be to symlink the script to `/usr/local/bin`

```
sudo ln -s /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/kernprof /usr/local/bin
```